# How do I style a div from grid to block display?

Tags: html, css

I have some divs in my html that I want to display side by side on desktop and display stacked on mobile. I used a grid to display them on desktop.
In my css file I added a media query

```css
@media(max-width:768px){
divselector {
display: block
}
}
```

But the divs still appear side by side.
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe position absolute will work

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your code, otherwise any answer will just be a rough guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly none of these suggestions worked for me.

I kept experimenting until I got exactly what I wanted. Its still grid based.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    div#dashboard_container,
    {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
    }
}
```

The thing is, if I specify only `#dashboard_container` in the media query the code doesn't work. I don't fully understand why that is.

A fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/parousia/L2w4uvzk/12/) demonstrating the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/datt265/hfmx6bp3/2/)

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>

            .container {
          font-size: 0;
        }

        .container div {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 100px;
          height: 30px;
          background: #000000;
          font-size: 12px;
        }

        .container div.a {
          width: 100px;
          background: #555555;
        }

        .container div.b {
          width: 100px;
          background: #333333;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
          .container {
            display: block;
          }
        }

        /* On screens that are 600px or less */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          .container {
            display: block;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position them with `absolute` when in mobile mode, so all of the divs will be stacked on each other

```css
.ex {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #bada55;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .ex {
    position:absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ex">1111</div>
<div class="ex">2222</div>
```